# FromQuery Is not working for nested types

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following request object :

```
    public record SampleRequest
    {
        public int PageSize { get; set; }
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }
        public List<FilterModel> Filters { get; set; }
    }

    public record FilterModel
    {
        public string PropertyName { get; set; }
        public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
    }
```

And I'm trying to populate it from query for a HttpGet as following :

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] SampleRequest request)
 {
       return Ok("");
 }
```

for testing I'm using SwaggerUI, but the binding it's not working for the Filter at all, it is always null. Any ideas?

Comment: What querystring are you passing to your action?

Comment: that was the problem, I was not passing the expected format, but the answer marked as solution, solved the mistery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case swagger can not help you to test. Use postman like:

localhost:5001?PageSize=10&PageNumber=1&Filters[0].PropertyName=test&Filters[0].PropertyValue=somevalue&Filters[1].PropertyName=test&Filters[1].PropertyValue=somevalue